# PHP file_get_contents for the same domain

Tags: php

I have the line below:

```
file_get_contents('http://mydomain.com/page1');
```

When using [CloudFare](http://cloudflare.com), a 403 Forbidden happened. How to get the content of a page in the same domain? Alternative for file_get_contents w/o being forbidden by CloudFare?

Comment: Try using `curl` instead. Maybe the host rejects unknown user agent.

Comment: I think curl is alternative solution.

Comment: 403 Forbidden isn't a PHP error code, but a HTTP error code. Try it using the relative path, or a file in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably some internal routing issue. Looks like you'll need to use the hostname CloudFlare sets up that bypasses CloudFlare and goes directly to server. From what I'm reading, it might be something like `direct.mydomain.com`.

See the following

- https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170166-General-website-security-guidelines
- https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168616-Why-isn-t-the-direct-subdomain-working-
- https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168536-Why-do-I-have-a-direct-connect-subdomain-